# Cannot execute (find) fetch command using rake via a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, fetch, rake, rakefile

I have read most missing binary in Rake that I could find, but this case is different because it works in my dev environment but not on Jenkins.

I am trying to invoke the fetch binary published by gruntworks 
(https://github.com/gruntwork-io/fetch)

it should be noted that the Rakefile works correctly on dev machines, but I cannot get it to work when it is invoked on a Jenkins Pipeline via a JenkinsFile.

I have a Rakefile with the following call

```
sh "fetch --repo 'https://github.com/gruntwork-io/gruntkms' --tag 'v0.0.5' --release-asset='gruntkms_linux_amd64' _tools/"
```

The binary in questions is 
There is the correct directory structure in place (complete contents redacted)

```
$ ls -al . 
drwxrwxr-x  2 1000 1000   4096 Jan 29 10:37 _tools

$ ls -al _tools 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 1000 1000       17 Jan 29 10:37 fetch -> fetch_linux_amd64
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   7651536 Jan 29 10:16 fetch_linux_amd64
```

The Path is correctly set to include the _tools directory.

```
export PATH='/home/qa/jenkins/workspace/RQ/_tools:/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

and yet, I get the following error:

```
sh: fetch: not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [fetch --repo 'https://github.com/gr...]
```

Even when I try to explicitely call the binary fetch, (which is a ln) i still get a script not found error code (127)

```
_tools/fetch --repo 'https://github.com/gruntwork-io/gruntkms' --tag 'v0.0.5' --release-asset='gruntkms_linux_amd64' _tools/
sh: _tools/fetch: not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [_tools/fetch --repo 'https://github.com/gr...]
```

I have also confirmed that the issue it still there with the latest version of the fetch binary (0.3.2). I didn't think that was the issue, but for the sake of certainty, I tried it.

Comment: show your printenv using
sh 'printenv'

Comment: in the end, I am not smart.
In fact, there was something wrong with the fetch binary from gruntworks, it couldn't be called outside it's own cd on the BM for some reason, the latest version actually does fix this. (0.3.2)
When I tested the new version, I was involuntarily overwriting the new version with the old version during the process.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of https://github.com/gruntwork-io/fetch (0.3.2) at the time of writing did solve.